# Django 1.7 - makemigrations not detecting changes - managed models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have just installed django 1.7 in my virtual env.

Then I manually created the following files:

```
service_bus/
service_bus/__init__.py
service_bus/django_settings.py
service_bus/models
service_bus/models/__init__.py
service_bus/models/dsp.py
service_bus/models/audience_type.py
service_bus/models/category.py
service_bus/models/audience.py
service_bus/models/dsp_config.py
service_bus/models/apsettings.py
```

So I have a settings file `service_bus/django_settings.py` and the `service_bus` app.

Then I did, on bash:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='service_bus.django_settings'
```

Then I just try to run makemigrations, but it says no changes are detected.

```
$ django-admin makemigrations
Loading properties from /etc/s1mbi0se/dmp.ini
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_6.W001) Some project unittests may not execute as expected.
    HINT: Django 1.6 introduced a new default test runner. It looks like this project was generated using Django 1.5 or earlier. You should ensure your tests are all running & behaving as expected. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#new-test-runner for more information.
No changes detected


$ django-admin makemigrations service_bus
Loading properties from /etc/s1mbi0se/dmp.ini
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_6.W001) Some project unittests may not execute as expected.
    HINT: Django 1.6 introduced a new default test runner. It looks like this project was generated using Django 1.5 or earlier. You should ensure your tests are all running & behaving as expected. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#new-test-runner for more information.
No changes detected in app 'service_bus'
```

In all my models I have something like

```
class APSettings(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'APSettings'
        app_label = 'service_bus'
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the `migrate` command first to scaffold the database schema. Then, you can run `makemigrations` for each app. Check the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) for more on this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you update your models.py file to actually import the models. For example in models.py you'd have  `from service_bus.models.audience import *`. The manage script goes over that file, imports all the models in audience.py and detects changes in there. If you did not add your new models to models.py then the manage script won't know about the new models in you models files.